# represent IP address as OID

Tags: ip, oid

how would I represent an IP address as an OID? is there any subtree for generic IP addresses? I'd have expected something like `{ iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) protocols ip v4(4) address 127 0 0 1 }` (for 127.0.0.1; `1.3.6.1` is the internet OID, but everything after that is just my example) but can't find it in the public repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems to be no such method until now, **I reserved the OID node **`1.3.6.1.4.1.43892.1863.791.0.<ip>` for this use**, `<ip>` being an IPv4 address in dotted decimal representation.

so the OID for "127.0.0.1" (the example in my original question) would be: `1.3.6.1.4.1.43892.1863.791.0.127.0.0.1`